# Обработка кнопки Back в зависимости от открытого файла в WebWiew

Tags: android-studio, webview

Есть WebWiew, загружаются локальные файлы из Assets. В html файлах есть ссылки на другие html файлы. Сейчас при нажатии кнопки Назад переходит назад по истории открытых файлов. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии Назад загружался определенный html файл в зависимости от того, какой сейчас открыт файл? Например - если открыт 02.html, при нажатии Назад открывать не ранее открытый файл, а 03.html. А если открыт 01.html, то выход из приложения.

Загружаю html так:

```
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/m01.html");
```

Обработчик кнопки Назад:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       if (web.canGoBack()) {
           web.goBack();
       } else {
           super.onBackPressed();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Разобрался... Узнать текущий адрес можно через getUrl()

Answer (score 0):

Сделал примерно так:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (web.getUrl().startsWith("file:///android_asset/02") ){
        web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/03.html");
        }
     else {
        if (web.getUrl().startsWith("file:///android_asset/01") )
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```